# React JS How can I print an array as new <li> <li> tag

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, use-state

I have a function that takes a single word for user input and find get a list of definitions for that word and fills an array with that data, but every time I print it on my webpage, it just displays the last item from the list. How can I print every element from the array in its own `<li></li>` and display it back to the user.

*.js

```
const [word, setWord] = useState([])
const arr = []


const defineWord = () =>{
        const newWord = document.getElementById('userDefinition').value
        client.define(newWord).then(function(result){
          for(let i = 0; i < result.definitions.length; i++) {
           
           console.log(result.definitions[i].definition)
           arr.push(result.definitions[i].definition)
           setWord(word => word = arr)
        }
    
         });
    }

return(
 <ol>
  {word.map(item => {
    return <li>{item}</li>;
   })}
 </ol>
)
```

Comment: `for () { const arr = []; arr.push(); setWord() }` <--- Do you see the problem? What do you think happens on every iteration in the loop?? You make a new empty array, you push to it, you set the array. Next iteration, you make an empty array, you push to it, you set the array...... So you are always setting a new array with one item.

Comment: `setWord(word => word = arr)` <-- why are you giving it a function??

Comment: Even if I put the array outside the for loop i get the same result

Answer (score 0):

Just try the `map` function and pass the array to `setWord`.

```
const [words, setWords] = useState([])

const defineWord = () =>{
        const newWord = document.getElementById('userDefinition').value
        client.define(newWord).then(function(result){
            const defenitions = result.definitions.map(definition => definition.definition);
            setWords(defenitions);
        });
    }

return(
 <ol>
  {words.map((item, index) => {
    return <li key={index}>{item}</li>;
   })}
 </ol>
)
```

Comment: got the follow error ```Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined```

Comment: can you check what `result` output? at best with `console.log`. PS: sorry had a typo

Comment: result just returns a list of definitions that relate to what the user has inputted, to make it easier you can just replace the for loop counting up by one and filling that up with the array

Comment: then just try `result.map()` when the result is already an aray.

Comment: Now it says ```result is not defined```

Comment: you want to join the chatroom to identify the problem more? Looks like `client.defined()` is outputting not the expected result: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235468/question-id-68597154

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following which worked:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

function App() {
  const [word, setWord] = useState([])

  const defineWord = () => {
    fetch('https://reqres.in/api/products')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
        setWord(data.data.filter(word => word.name === 'cerulean'))
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
      })
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    defineWord();
  },[])

  return (
    <ol>
      {word.map(item => {
        return <li key={item.id}>{item.name}</li>;
      })}
    </ol>
  )
}

export default App;
```

I didn't use client.define since I don't know what that is, but if it looks like it's being used to fetch data so that should replace fetch.  The useEffect
function is being used to display the data when the page is loaded.

Comment: @Sysix Thanks, you're right.  I just tested that, and updated the answer.

Comment: If ```client.define``` was just an array, how would the code look?

Answer (score 0):

You can get your code to run with just 2 changes:

1. Instead of `setWord(word => word = arr)`, just call `setWord(arr)` - that is, update the state to pass the full array with the definitions instead of a function
2. Move the `setWord` call outside of the `for` loop - right now you're overriding the state on every `for iteration, which is why the component is not rendering what you're expecting

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul>{arr.map((item)=>{return <li>{item}<li>})}</ul>
```